set trigger in Angular component in for loop
I do have an Angular component in a for loop like this:
<div *ngFor="let schedule of schedules">
   <my-app-component [schedule]="schedule"></my-app-component>
</div>

The MyAppComponent looks like this:
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app-component',
  templateUrl: '...',
  styleUrls: ['...'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class MyAppComponent implements OnInit {

  public disableButtonTrigger: boolean;

 ngOnInit() {
     this.disableButtonTrigger = false;
 }

 someFunction() {
     ...
     this.disableButtonTrigger = true; // this should set disableButtonTrigger to true only for this component and not for all components in the loop
     ...
  }

In the MyAppComponent is a boolean trigger to disable buttons in this component.
My problem now is if I set disableButtonTrigger = true than all buttons in all components in the for- loop are disabled.
May aim would be that only the buttons on the specific component should be diasbled and not in all component.
How can I achive this?

How exactly are you setting the disableButtonTrigger = true? Via the parent component? Please add enough code so we can understand better what you are implementing.

Cannot reproduce in StackBlitz, there it's working as expected: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-npqg8n?file=src%2Fmain.ts Please add enough code to reproduce the problem. In the StackBlitz I added two buttons for each component, the second one disables the first one.

MAybe its because my "MyAppComponent" is defined in a parent @NgModule and is not standalone.

That shouldn't make a difference.

You are right. Blame on me - the for loop is in the component - I am so sorry - thanks for your help.
